# Output 12 Times Tables Java

Tags: java

I am trying to output 12 times tables. Where it will go through all the times tables from 1 to 12. And each times table will go up to *12. For examples, the output should look something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24

3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36

...

12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96  108  120  132  144
```

Here is the code I have so far, I seem to be very close. But I am struggling with perfecting it.

```
public class Tables  {

public void generateTable()  
{
  //Put the code for your times-table here
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i=1; i<=12; i++) 
    {
        for(j=i; j<=i*12; j = j+1)
        {
            System.out.print(j*i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Tables t = new Tables();
    t.generateTable();
}
```

}

I am receiving the following output for this code:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 

4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 

9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72 75 78 81 84 87 90 93 96 99 102 105 108
```

...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the inner loop, you only want to go from 1 to 12 instead of from `i` to `i*12`.

You could also declare `i` and `j` more local in the respective loop where the initialization is done.

Comment: As stated in the answer, the inner loop should start at 1.